# Delete dir files on every sunday 12noon

Tags: php, timestamp, delete-file

Holla,

Guys i am currently deleting sesstions if created time is more than 9 hours but i wish for it to clean the _sessions dir on every sunday at 12noon.

can someone here help me out with the logic ?

my code

```
$ses_dir = '_sessions/';
if ($handle = opendir($ses_dir)) {
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');  
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
        $filelastmodified = filemtime($ses_dir . $file);
        if((time() - $filelastmodified) > 9*60*60) {
            unlink($ses_dir . $file);
        }
    }
    closedir($handle); 
}
```

really thankful for your help in advance

Comment: Setup/run a cronjob

Comment: I can help you out with the code indentation though

Comment: @RiggsFolly will really appreciate it if you could help me out.

Comment: @brombeer i wish to achieve it without cronjob

Comment: Are you running on a unix/linux or Windows?

Comment: Don't you want to have a scheduler at all, or is it specifically cron you don't want to use? If you don't want a scheduler at all, then you need to manually go in and either empty the dir or trigger a script that empties the dir (don't see a reason to write a script though, since it would basically just be one command either way) every Sunday at 12.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Linux hosting on Godaddy

Comment: So a CRON Job is your best solution. Do you know what a CRON is?

Comment: `cron` is designed for exactly this sort of task. Why don't you want to use a `cron` job?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I have never done it before

Comment: The you will need to do a little research, there are 1000's of tutorials out there, but first check that your hosting plan allows you to create a CRON

Comment: Never say no to a solution just because you've never done it before. See it as an opportunity to learn new things instead.